# Image from webserver is not shown in web browser

Tags: permissions, apache2

I am new to Ubuntu and recently I installed xampp 1.8.1 on my Ubuntu 12.10. My problem is that image from server can not be shown. My code is

```
 <div class="sideBlock unSung">
     <h4>Unsung heroes...</h4>
     <a href="#"> <img src="_images/1_full.jpg" alt="Midnight Run" width="99" height="135" /> </a>

     <a href="#"><img src="_images/2d7y3ki.jpg" alt="Wyatt Earp" width="99" height="135" /></a>
  </div>
```

Here, in my address bar I use

```
 http://localhost/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html
```

and I want to show image after 'Unsung heroes' text but it only shows some link and no image.

But when I use the following

```
 file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html
```

images are shown after 'Unsung heroes' text.

It works well on Windows platform.

As a new user, I have very little knowledge about file permissions, `chmod`, `chown` etc. I use `ls -l` in my terminal window in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images` directory, and I see this:

```
sabbir@sabbir-pc:/opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images$ ls -l
total 300
-rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir 204067 Feb 24  2010 1_full.jpg
-rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  75789 Nov 13  2009 2d7y3ki.jpg
-rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  23692 Apr 21  2010 6AB32AE44600435B9DE0FB5EBA24A912.gif
```

I also go to

```
/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.config
```

to find `EnableMMAP off` and  `EnableSendfile off` which is already `#` off.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your files with read write permissions JUST for the owner but not to the group or other (world universe).

Try the next in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod 775 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images
```

This will provide read permissions for the world universe of users, this way you will be able to see the files without problem when browsing in a localhost environment or the net.

The reason because of the files and images are properly shown when you run `file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html` is because of the owner of the files is allowed to read/write over them. But the rest of the people won't be able to reach certain files that won't meet the requirements for worldwide access.

Additionally, you may need to assign anonymous read permissions to the folder where the files resides by running `sudo chmod 775 /opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images -R`

`-R` = Recursively: All the files/folders inside will also be affected.

Please give this a try and let us know if this is doing the work for you, if you need further assistance don't hesitate to let us know by dropping a message and the contents of this answer may be changed or deleted depending on your results.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You should not assign execute permissions to files.
You should not recursively assign 775.

If you are going to do the above, instead do this:

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

or

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images -type f -exec chmod ugo+r {} \;
```

I once worked with someone who had a habit of telling people to cd to a directory and recursively chmod 777 things, but one day the person he was telling to do it forgot to say the cd command had returned the message "directory not found" and so he borked the whole server.

Comment: what is a permission that is read/write but not executable? I've been using `chmod -R a+rw  static/images` but that does not *remove* exec permissions if they were set before...

Comment: @dcsan that's an advantage of using symbolic notation - you can set the bits individually. To remove permissions use `-`, like `chmod o-x` to remove execute permission for "others". Setting octal permissions, as demonstrated in this answer, affects all the bits at once, so `chmod 644` removes all execution bits (6 is read write, 4 is read only)